# Хуки функций C++

Tags: c++, ram

В попытках подробно изучить механизм "хуков", наткнулся на статью [Intercepting API function calls](https://sudonull.com/post/177522-Intercepting-API-function-calls), я задался вопросом касательно некоторых моментов. 
Есть функция, определяющая относительный адрес между функциями:

```
size_t CalcDisplacement(void* lpStartAddress, void* lpEndAddress) {
    return reinterpret_cast<char*>(lpEndAddress) - (reinterpret_cast<char*>(lpStartAddress) + 5);
}
```

И так вопрос, почему при вычислении адреса кастятся в `char*` для его определения? При моих попытках кастить в что-то еще, они приводили к ***Access Violation***.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что `char` это один байт. Соответственно расчеты проводятся побайтово. Когда Вы кастили во что-то другое вы прибавляли и отнимали не байт, а столько байтов сколько заложено в том типе данных в который Вы кастили. Посмотрите "Арифметика указателей".